# catching events for SMS in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I like to know whether a user actually confirmed sending an SMS or if he just pressed the back button without sending the sms. While in Android and even in iOS this is simply done with a callback, WP8 does not offer any obvious solution for this.

So I was wondering if there is an event that gets fired if an sms has been sent and not gets fired if the sms has not been sent.

Possibly one could catch this event to check whether the SMS was actually sent or got cancelled.

The sms itslef is beeing initiated from within the app where I like to catch the SMS events.

Just to clarify, I do not want to send the SMS automatically - which I know is not possible in WP. All I need to know is whether the user actually sent an SMS or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't possible currently on WP8. If you're interested in seeing this in future releases please fill in a [wpdev uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform) suggestion with your usecase and why you're interested in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Windows Phone world.
SmsComposeTask is a launcher API derived from ChooserBase<> and implement an action of type fire and forget. So, you can't get any data from launcher.

I admit that it would be good to know whether are messages sent to user.
Best regards